# Wordpress image cannot be displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I took over this job from others and I was asked to replace an image by another, but after I uploaded the new image to Media Library and modified the code, new image did not show up any more. The code done by previous guy is like this

```
background: url(images/logoCA.png)
```

Image I uploaded is named "Logo_TM.png"  so I modified it to

```
background: url(images/Logo_TM.png)
```

That's the only thing I changed but the image does not show any more...

Today, I found previous guy used FileZilla to upload files, so I tried to upload through FileZilla. I uploaded my image to the same folder as he uploaded previous image (The path is *wp-content/themes/sportscreen/images/filename* ). But...image still did not show. I am frustrated, please help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the image doesn't show, the path is probably wrong. Or there might be CSS overriding it. Without seeing the actual site, and more info, it's impossible to say. Where is the CSS-file placed, in comparison to the image-folder? Because you're having a link to `images/imagefile`- which means the CSS-file needs to be in the same folder as the `image`-subfolder to work.

Comment: Try to replace image without change any place of code

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach the website url, it is "ca.thesportscreen.com" and the logo should be showed on the left top corner.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, the images are also saved on the DB, so you should check it out.

You can check this post out that explains exactly where your image could be properly loaded.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/where-does-wordpress-store-images-on-your-site/

```
 "Information about your uploads is stored in database as a attachment 
 post type under the posts table."
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, but I just logged into the back end to check it out and it was there... file was under "wp-content/uploads/2017/04" but still not showed up on website...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the file locations are:

```
wp-content/themes/sportscreen/images/Logo_TM.png
wp-content/themes/sportscreen/style.css
```

If so, the css rule should be (indeed):

```
background: url(images/Logo_TM.png);
```

Make sure it's not being overwritten by another css rule - you might want to add *!important* - so it would look like this:

```
background: url(images/Logo_TM.png) !important;
```

If the css file is located elsewhere, say

```
wp-content/themes/sportscreen/css/style.css
```

You should go like this:

```
background: url(../images/Logo_TM.png) !important;
```

And so on.

Edit -

Forgot to mention, make sure that **http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/sportscreen/images/Logo_TM.png** is actually accessible from within the webbrowser.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, but I tried to change code like "background: url(../images/Logo_TM.png) !important;" but the image is still not there...can I get a conclusion that there is no other style overwrites this rule (since use important, but it does not show yet). Plus, I tried to visit the the url you mentioned above, image is totally accessible through web-browser I just attach the entire url for this image (https://ca.thesportscreen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo1.png)

Comment: The image is NOT in the theme's directory so you'll have to use its full URL `background: url(https://ca.thesportscreen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo1.png);`.

Comment: Seems like it's a cache issue, open your css file in your webbrowser, you'll notice whether the updates you make on your css file are taking effect or not.

Comment: the file changes indeed .... but there is no image displaying on web...I am frustrated and confused now.